# how can i fix this sum grouped rows query?

Tags: postgresql

Starting from the last two queries, how can I use the first one?.

```
select t.columna1,(sum(v.val::float) as suma from t
cross join lateral unnest (string_to_array(columna2,',') as v(val)
group by t.columna1;
```

in the first one, together with the user_id and I see who is in the pos_payment table

```
SELECT DISTINCT pos_payment.pos_order_id, pos_order.user_id, SUM(pos_order.amount_paid) FROM 
pos_order
LEFT JOIN pos_payment ON pos_order.id = pos_payment.pos_order_id
GROUP BY pos_payment.pos_order_id , pos_order.user_id;

SELECT DISTINCT pos_payment.pos_order_id, pos_order.user_id , pos_order.amount_paid FROM 
pos_order
LEFT JOIN pos_payment ON pos_order.id = pos_payment.pos_order_id
GROUP BY pos_payment.pos_order_id , pos_order.user_id , pos_order.amount_paid ;
```